# Year over Year Variance Calculation Error "EARLIER/EARLIEST" refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

While trying to calculate Year over Year variance (unsuccessfully for 2 days now), I get the following error message.

> EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist.

```
YOY Variance = var PreviousYearPrinBal = CALCULATE(SUM(Deals[Principal Balance]),FILTER(ALL(Deals[Close Date].[Year]),Deals[Close Date].[Year] = EARLIER(Deals[Close Date].[Year])))
return
if(PreviousYearPrinBal = BLANK(), BLANK(), Deals[PrincipalBalance] - PreviousYearPrinBal)
```

In a different SO question, there is a different approach which gives me the following error:

> A column specified in the call to function 'SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR' is not of type DATE. This is not supported.

```
yoy = CALCULATE([PrincipalBalance], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Deals[Close Date].[Year]))
```

While I have some idea of what these mean, I do not have an idea of how to fix them. Here is my table.

[image]

And Here is what I expect as the result.

[image]

I've tried posting this question in Power BI community but haven't received an answer yet. [Calculate Year over Year Variance.](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Calculate-Year-over-Year-Variance-Earlier-Function-Not-Working/m-p/526909)

ACTUAL DATA SAMPLE:

[image]

Comment: Please post an example of your data.

Comment: @Sid29, I don't understand. I need to calculate the variance in Principal Balance year over year. The images show the data.

Comment: So these principal balances are not aggregated over each other and that's the actual data ? if that's it, then it's fine. Let me try

Comment: I gotcha. Yes, these are aggregates of individual dates. I can upload a picture of the actual data, give me a second.

Comment: lol... I will update the answer accordingly to your data then.

Comment: @Sid29 sorry about that. Just uploaded.

Comment: updated the answer accordingly again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Created Year and Year Difference Column (Calculated Column)

```
Year = YEAR(Table1[Date])
Year Difference = Table1[Year] - Min(Table1[Year])
```

2) Created the Variance (Measure)

```
Variance = 

   Var current_YearDifference = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Year Difference])  

   Var Current_PrincipalBalance = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Principal Balance]),FILTER(ALL(Table1), Table1[Year Difference] = (current_YearDifference)))                                            

   Var Previous_PrincipalBalance = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Principal Balance]),FILTER(ALL(Table1), Table1[Year Difference] = (current_YearDifference - 1)))                                  

Return if(current_YearDifference <> 0, (Current_PrincipalBalance - Previous_PrincipalBalance), 0)
```

3) Finally Created the Variance in terms of Percentage (Measure),

```
Variance in terms of Percentage = 

   Var current_YearDifference = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Year Difference])  

   Var Current_PrincipalBalance = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Principal Balance]),FILTER(ALL(Table1), Table1[Year Difference] = (current_YearDifference)))                                 

   Var Previous_PrincipalBalance = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Principal Balance]),FILTER(ALL(Table1), Table1[Year Difference] = (current_YearDifference - 1)))                                  

Return if(current_YearDifference <> 0, ((Current_PrincipalBalance - Previous_PrincipalBalance) / Previous_PrincipalBalance), 0)
```

### My Final Output

[image: Final Output on the Power BI Dashboard]

The Principal Balance has the function SUM selected on the Values Pane of the Output Table, where as the Year is Don't Summarize.

### My Best Practice

1. Always Use Vars when creating Complex Measures to simplify the
   formula.
2. Then return only a part of the Measure to check if the output is as expected.

Kindly let me know, if it helps or not.

Comment: Works perfect, yes, I see that Principal Bal is summed but the date is not summarized.